# Apache POI Draw Line Shape with arrow in Excel From To

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a code that outputs a line with an arrow. But the direction is wrong since the arrow direction is always pointing to the west direction. See screenshot below. Is there a way to set the line (from-direction) to (to-direction)?

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

       Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

       CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
       Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

       ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
       anchor.setCol1(5);
       anchor.setRow1(5); 
       anchor.setCol2(0);
       anchor.setRow2(17); 

       XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
       shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
       shape.setLineWidth(0.3);

       //apache POI sets first shape Id to 1. It should be 0.
       shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setId(shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().getId()-1);

       CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr();
       CTLineProperties lineProperties = shapeProperties.getLn();

       CTLineEndProperties lineEndProperties = org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTLineEndProperties.Factory.newInstance();
       lineEndProperties.setType(STLineEndType.TRIANGLE);
       lineEndProperties.setLen(STLineEndLength.LG);
       lineEndProperties.setW(STLineEndWidth.LG);

       lineProperties.setHeadEnd(lineEndProperties);
```

[This picture always pointing to west direction, I need it to set the direction of arrow base on the anchor col and row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuFQE.png)

Comment: Set the tail end (`lineProperties.setTailEnd(lineEndProperties);`) instead of setting the head end?